# React zoom in page by default

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

is there a chance that I can set the default zoom level of the page e.g. to 110%.
So, when you enter the website, it is automatically zoomed in by 10% more then it would be standard (100%).

Thanks a lot

I found a issue here with import detectZoom from 'detect-zoom' but I think this is not the way to go

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this i think cause browser zoom is something that is personalized and everyone has its zoom on size that suits best.